# How to advance multiple Enumerators, or "But what about FizzBuzzBoozz?"

Tags: ruby, enumerator

This is a rather unorthodox way to do the classic [FizzBuzz exercise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437/what-is-your-solution-to-the-fizzbuzz-problem), but it's just to illustrate the problem (and hey, it might be fast if you want to fizzbuzz to a billion).

```
fizzer = ( Array.new( 2, '' ) << 'Fizz' ).cycle
buzzer = ( Array.new( 4, '' ) << 'Buzz' ).cycle

(1..100).each do |number|
  fizzbuzz = fizzer.next + buzzer.next # this line is giving me problems.
  puts ( fizzbuzz.empty? ? number : fizzbuzz )
end
```

How to generalize this code to accept a hash like {3 => 'Fizz', 5 => 'Buzz', 7 => 'Boozz'} ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an array of Fizzers, Buzzers, and Boozzers. Then in the loop call `next` on each fooer in that array and then sum the results with `inject`:

```
# The sort is needed so it prints fizzbuzz, not buzzfizz
# (hashes being unordered and all)
fooers = the_hash.sort_by {|k,v| k}.map do |k,v|
  ( Array.new(k - 1, '') << v ).cycle
end

(1..100).each do |number|
  fizzbuzz = fooers.map(&:next).inject(:+)
  puts ( fizzbuzz.empty? ? number : fizzbuzz )
end
```

Comment: Ah. .map.inject, I couldn't figure that out. Sideline, why does #map needs an ampersand and #inject can do without?

Comment: @steenslag: `inject` is specifically written, so it can take a block or a symbol argument. `map` however can only take a block so you need the `&` to convert the symbol to a block (going through `Symbol#to_proc`). Why `inject` was written so it can take a symbol and `map` was not, I don't know, but I suspect it had something to do with `inject` being considered particularly slow before and the fact that using a symbol instead of a block speeds it up significantly.